# zxing-android-embedded: Load new Fragment from continous scan

Tags: android, android-fragments, zxing

I´ve the following problem: I want to load a new Fragment from my QR Activity. I start the activity from my fragment like this:

```
IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(this).setCaptureActivity(QrHorizontalActivity.class).initiateScan();
```

Then in the scan activity I want to load my new fragment:

```
       @Override
        public void barcodeResult(BarcodeResult result) {
SwipeOverviewFragment.newInstance().add_fragment(R.id.barcode_scanner,curr_activity, detail_frag);
```

Why will this not work? Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for calling fragment;

```
   FragmentTransaction fragmenttransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   SwipeOverviewFragment regcomplainfragment = new SwipeOverviewFragment();
   fragmenttransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, regcomplainfragment).addToBackStack("tag");
   fragmenttransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Not able to call getSupportFragmentManager, maybe cause the inheritance: public class `QrHorizontalActivity extends CaptureActivity {`  ?? thanks

Comment: Are you using fragment?

Comment: If yes, then try getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: of course! but no appcombatactivity for the qr scanner!

Comment: getActivity() does also not work, it will not find this method. Really do not know whats my problem here :/